# Horizontzl Grid View in Android

Tags: android

I want to implement a horizontal grid view.I have googled for that.But there is no solution found.Is there any way to make a horizontal grid view?

I found that horizontal scrolling is possible with android gallery.Is it possible to have a gallery with multiple rows?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Try out these different projects from Github. Might give you an idea.

1. [android-viewflow](https://github.com/pakerfeldt/android-viewflow)
2. [DevsmartLib-Android](https://github.com/dinocore1/DevsmartLib-Android)
3. [GalleryView](https://github.com/trivedikamal1/GalleryView)